# mysql query get last n number of records from two tables with table fields

Tags: mysql

```
image1=emp_detail (table),
image2=emp_atnd (table),
image3=result that i get right now,
image4 =expected result's image.
```

[image: emp_detail table]

[image: emp_atnd table]

[image: result]

[image: expected result]

Here I having two tables first is emp_detail table and second is emp_atnd table . and last one image is that I want in my result but right now I'm getting result like image 3 with the given query.

```
SELECT `emp_id`,`emp_date`,`first_nm` FROM `emp_atnd`,`emp_detail` WHERE `emp_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `emp_detail`)AND YEAR(`emp_date`)=2014 LIMIT 0,4
```

Why am I not getting the result I want?

Comment: Can you name your table before their image please ?

Comment: put order by desc and then limit 0,4

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT emp_id,emp_date,first_nm FROM emp_atnd JOIN emp_details on
>   emp_id = id WHERE YEAR(emp_date)=2014 LIMIT 0,4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `emp_id`,`emp_date`,`first_nm` FROM `emp_atnd` a,`emp_detail` b 
WHERE b.`emp_id`=a.id AND YEAR(`emp_date`)=2014 LIMIT 0,4
```

Comment: This is just nearest result but i dont want like this i just want last 4 records from emp_atnd table that is image 2 table and result shoud be like image no 4 only how it is posible

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
SELECT emp_atnd .emp_id,emp_atnd.emp_date,emp_detail.first_nm 
  FROM emp_atnd,emp_detail 
  WHERE emp_atnd .emp_id=emp_detail.id AND YEAR(emp_date)=2014 
  ORDER BY emp_atnd .emp_id
  LIMIT 0,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Do order by desc, For example i take emp_id as main row, you can set as per your requirement. it will give you bottom to top records, then get 0 to 4 records.
May it will help you.

```
SELECT `emp_id`,`emp_date`,`first_nm` FROM `emp_atnd` a,`emp_detail` b 
WHERE b.`emp_id`=a.id AND YEAR(`emp_date`)=2014 order by emp_id desc LIMIT 0,4
```